# cardano-cli calculate-min-fee expects Shelley era transaction body

Tags: cardano-cli

When using cardano-cli version 1.27.0 I want to calculate the min fee for the transaction. The procedure is to create a dummy transaction and using that to calculate the fee.

When creating the dummy transaction using:

`cardano-cli transaction build-raw  --tx-in 1...x#2 --tx-out addr1...a+0 --tx-out addr1...b+0 --invalid-hereafter 30458092 --fee 0 --out-file tx-1622014393N.dummy`

The transaction file then contains the correct era indicator:

`"type":"TxBodyMary"`

However, when I then calculate min fee on this transaction, an error occurs:

`cardano-cli transaction calculate-min-fee --tx-body-file /tmp/tx.dummy --protocol-params-file /tmp/protocol.json --tx-in-count 1 --tx-out-count 1 --witness-count 2 --byron-witness-count 0 --mainnet`

Response:

`Command failed: transaction calculate-min-fee  Error: /tmp/tx.dummy: TextEnvelope decode error: DecoderErrorDeserialiseFailure "Shelley TxBody" (DeserialiseFailure 1 "expected list of length 3")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like the transaction is created with a different version of `cardano-cli`.

Can you please confirm the file `/tmp/tx.dummy` is the same as `tx-1622014393N.dummy`?

Comment: Yes. It turns out I indeed created with 1.26.2. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

From you example, it looks like your `--tx-out-count` is `2` and not `1`, unsure about the `witness-count`, should be `1` I guess. Could fixing this help?